# Overriding an Entity setter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

When a `setFoo()` method from entity `Bar` is called, I would like to accomplish some kind of logic like fetching object from the database. I'm thinking about creating a listener which handles that kind of logic but I would preferer to create a kind of entity wrapper or manager which overrides `setFoo()` method and which would be executed transparently when `Bar::setFoo()` is called.

The idea is to override the mentioned method application wide in a transparent way, so for example when submitting a form bind() method would also run the overriding setFoo() method instead of `Bar::setFoo()`.

After a bit of research i found no way to wrap my object to override Bar::setFoo(). Does any one knows how could i listen for calls on Bar::setFoo()? As prePersist, postLoad, onFlush, etc event listeners are not a valid solutions cause they are called after object validation i'm trying with the exposed solution on the following link, but after a bit of testing i think they can listen to method calls except everywhere except for entity methods, http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSAopBundle#transaction-management

Does any one know how could I accomplish that?

EDIT: Finally had to use Form::Events in conjunction with an EntityManager. The result wasn't as clean as expected but functional.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention yes i do.

Comment: Ok.  As a rule you really don't want D2 objects accessing the database.  So I can't really help there.  However, since you mentioned form binding, I suspect a Symfony 2 DataTransformer is probably what you want.  Instead of an abstract foo/bar question perhaps you could provide a specific use case that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Cerad, thanks for the reply. Do you know how could i create a listener which listens for calls to Bar::setFoo()?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify

Comment: Hi Cerad, what's your intention on posting the above link? Do you have any clear idea on how to call custom listeners inside Entity setters? If so could you please let us know? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing a Proxy object?

```
class BarProxy extends Bar
{
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    // override all Bar methods and delegate to $this->bar->{method}()

    public function setFoo($foo)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bernhard, Is it possible or recommended to inject an entity manager inside a Proxy object?

Comment: Sure you can do that.